# MVC - Toggling display options in a reused partial view

Tags: model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm wondering what is the correct way to toggle visibility on a partial view component, used by multiple screens.

For example: if the **ItemOrder** entity has these fields, and the corresponding edit view has 3 input fields:

- Cost - (Only editable on Page A)
- Quantity - (Don't show on Page B)
- Colour - (Show as disabled on Page C)

And assume that the controllers for these 3 pages each have their own model as the root, e.g.:

- PageAModel

  - ItemOrder
- PageBModel

  - ItemOrder
- PageCModel

  - ItemOrder

How can I best control these view modes across these pages?

Options that come to mind are:

- View model wraps the **ItemOrder** entity, and has properties such as IsPriceEditable, IsColourEditEnabled, etc? These get set in the controller.
- A **ItemOrderViewOptions** class is inserted to the ViewBag, and the responsibility of each controller to insert.

Any suggestions on a standard/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what you can do with EditorTemplates I do something similar along these lines:

Create an EditorTemplate for each concrete type aka:

```
/EditorTemplates/PageAModel.cshtml
/EditorTemplates/PageBModel.cshtml
/EditorTemplates/PageCModel.cshtml
```

Within these you can then explicitly control your input fields as you like, as each template will only be used with that concrete type. So as you have specified:

- Cost - (Only editable on Page A)
- Quantity - (Don't show on Page B)
- Colour - (Show as disabled on Page C)

Then from a common page or seperate ones (as you like) simply call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ThePageModel)
```

Which should render the form as you have defined in the EditorTemplates for that class type.